# Angular Reactive Form, dynamically create form controls

Tags: angular, forms

I have a reactive form which need to have one or more simple input field. So I am doing a *ngFor to go ovr the array of object and can successfully create the labels. I can also create the input field but I don't know how to track the entered value in it. I need to collect the inputs entered by user and send it to the backend.

How do I do it?
I did research and found out I should use an array to hold all possible number of generated input fields. But how do I create the form-control for it.

```
    <form [formGroup]="SignupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group p-mb-4"  *ngFor="let _insertField of actionsetSelected; let i=index">
         <label class="formLabel" *ngIf="_insertField" for="userInput">{{_insertField.name}}</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insertNames" [formControlName]="i">
      </div>
    <button label="Submit" ></button>
</form>

 

in my ts:

 
this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
    'insertNames':new FormArray([])
  });
```

Comment: See this nested reactive form example ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-deep-nested?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple.. just use `valueChanges` on the form or on any of the form fields.. for example.

let's assume I have a form filed by the name `email`, in my ts file I can do the following.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.SignupForm.email.valueChanges.pipe(
       tap(value: string) => { // value is the email the user entered
    
           // do what ever you want with value     

       }
    ).subscribe()
}
```

you can of course listen to the form object like so..

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.SignupForm.valueChanges.pipe(
       tap(value: string) => { // value is your form object containing all the fields
    
           // do what ever you want with value     

       }
    ).subscribe()
}
```

**DONT FORGET TO UNSCUBSCRIBE !!**